# Failed Ubuntu package download

Tags: package-management, repository, downloads

I have a problem downloading packages with ubuntu server 18.04. I have had it working before. However, I have reinstalled the operating system and can no longer remember how I fixed it last time. I believe that last time I enabled/downloaded repositories. Can anyone help me?

```
sudo apt install shorewall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package shorewall is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'shorewall' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please tell us which packages you cannot download. And please tell us the error output. Edit the original question (do not answer in comments). Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code' (to make it easier for us to read).

Comment: However, it won't download any package @sudodus

Comment: `shorewall` is in the repository 'universe'. Is it activated in your Ubuntu Server? Please run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and after that `sudo apt update` and try again to install `shorewall` with `sudo apt install shorewall`

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any other generic ones that i may have to install as well for other packages? But thanks this did the trick!

Comment: There are a few repositories ... Please ask again when there is a program package, that you cannot install, and I or someone else can help you check what you need to install it. Good luck :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Thanks for all of the help! I have finally started setting it up!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking if the package `shorewall` is listed under a different name by executing:

`sudo apt-cache search shorewall`

You may also want to search for the repository for `shorewall` from Google and add it to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

You can try: https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/shorewall/download and download the Shorewall .deb package for all architectures there, and install with dpkg

You should also look at http://www.shorewall.org/download.htm as they list the different requirements as well